# stack expects each tensor to be equal size, but got [1, 48] at entry 0 and [1, 16] at entry 1

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

while executing this part of the code:
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
model.train()
train_loss = 0.0

```
for batch in tqdm(train_loader, desc=f'Epoch {epoch + 1}/{num_epochs}'):
    inputs = {k: v.to(device) for k, v in batch.items()}
    optimizer.zero_grad()

    outputs = model(**inputs)
    loss = outputs.loss
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    train_loss += loss.item()

train_loss /= len(train_loader)
```

I am getting following error:
stack expects each tensor to be equal size, but got [1, 48] at entry 0 and [1, 16] at entry 1

i don't know what to do

i searched on google too, but they cant help

Comment: Voting to close, please add an [mre].

Comment: you're not showing any relevant code. the error is on a call to torch.stack, which might be in your model or in your data loader code, neither of which are present here.